# Позиционирование DIV блока

Tags: jquery, javascript, html5

Доброго времени суток.
У меня вот такая задача связанная с позиционированием. Мне нужно сделать такую задачу как в yandex.ru после ввода вопроса в поисковик и появлении результатов поиска, при прокрутке страницы вниз блок с введенным вопросом остается на вверху.

Как позиционировать блок я знаю - `position:fixsed`, а чтобы `div` оставался на вверху страницы с отступом `10px` и не прокручивался. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
     if ($(document).scrollTop()<240){
         $('#blockMenu').removeClass("blockMenuFixed"); 
        }
    else{
     $('#blockMenu').addClass("blockMenuFixed"); 
    }
    });
  });
**CSS**
#blockMenu{
margin-left:18px;
color:#fff; 
position: relative;
}

.blockMenuFixed{
top:10px !important;
position:fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

При загрузке определяйте текущий offset().top, если страница проскроллена больше, прибавляете marginTop.

```
// <div id="hit"></div>
var hitTop = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  hitTop = $('#hit').offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('#hit').stop().animate({marginTop: ($(document).scrollTop() < hitTop ? '0' : $(document).scrollTop() - hitTop)+'px'});
    // или, если нужно моментально:
    // $('#hit').css({marginTop: ($(document).scrollTop() < hitTop ? '0' : $(document).scrollTop() - hitTop)+'px'});
    });
  });
```

Если позиционирование абсолютное, не пользуйтесь `margin-top` в стилях (`top: 10px;` пойдет)

Перечитал впорос, возможно, вы об этом:

```
<!--<div style="height: 10px; margin-bottom: -10px;"></div> -->
<div id="hit" style="padding-top: 10px;">
  <div>main block</div>
</div>
```

Код в этом случае менять не надо.

Comment: На счет 2го кода, это ты так сразу задаешь верхний отступ, а необходимо чтобы когда мы начинаем прокручивать страницу вниз, при достижения верхней границы ДИВ не скрывался оставался на месте а страница прокручивалась. при обратном чтобы становилась на место

Comment: Замените в `$(document).ready` первую строку

    hitTop = $('#hit').offset().top-10; // =) все просто)

Все стили тогда можно убрать (margin, padding). Будет работать для любого дива, но указать надо `position: absolute;`, иначе вся страница прокручиваться будет.

Comment: Собственно, [demo](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test29.php) =)

Comment: Вот решил проблему, спасибо всем кто принял участие в решении задачи

Comment: Я исходил из того, что 1) fixed - не кроссбраузерно, 2) скрипт выше универсален (можно доработать под класс). А так, конечно, в большинстве браузеров это тоже будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Позиционируйте его относительно строки поиска:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div>Поиск</div>
  <div style = "position:absolute; top: 30px">Подсказка</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это не то, если блок находится ниже 30px то получается если я пропишу 30px, блок отобразится  не в нужном положении, а мне нужно чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз когда верхняя граница достигает ДИВА чтобы при прокрутке блок оставался на месте а страница прокручивалась

Answer (score 0):

Может что-то вроде этого?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <style>
      body{padding:0;margin:0;}
      #header{background:#f00;position:fixed;height:30px;width:100%;}
      #wrapper{padding-top:30px;}
      #page{background:#eee;height:1000px;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page">Page</div>
        <div>Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Высота на #page здесь просто, чтобы не забивать контентом